# Ordinal encoder issues with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, ordinal

I have a dataframe with blank spaces as missing values, so I have replaced them with NaN values by using a regex. The problem that I have is when I want to use ordinal encoding for replacing categorical values. My code so far is the following:

```
    x=pd.DataFrame(np.array([30,"lawyer","France",
                             25,"clerk","Italy",
                             22," ","Germany",
                             40,"salesman","EEUU",
                             34,"lawyer"," ",
                             50,"salesman","France"]
                             
            ).reshape(6,3))
    x.columns=["age","job","country"]
    x = x.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

    oe=preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()
    df.job=oe.fit_transform(df["job"].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

I got the following error:

```
Input contains NaN
```

I would like that the job column gets replaced with numbers such as: [1,2,-1,3,1,3].

Comment: from sklearn v1.0, it will no longer complain that input contains NaN as "OrdinalEncoder will also passthrough missing values that are indicated by np.nan" from https://scikit-learn.org/1.0/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with `factorize`, notice here is category start with 0

```
x.job.mask(x.job==' ').factorize()[0]
Out[210]: array([ 0,  1, -1,  2,  0,  2], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: thank you, really nice answer, one more question, in the case that I would like to use OrdinalEncoding() what should I do? replace the NaN with a string like "empty" for example? would that be a good choice?

Comment: @Little yes keep it as  empty, after `df.job=oe.fit_transform(df["jov"].values.reshape(-1,1))`, change the empty row to -1 ~

Answer (score 2):

`sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder` doesn't allow `NaN`. If you want to use it, you need to drop `NaN` before fetching to `OrdinalEncoder`, assign the result back to the column and `fillna`

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

oe = preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()
x.loc[x.job.notna(), ['job']] = oe.fit_transform(x["job"].dropna().values.reshape(-1,1))
x['job'] = x.job.fillna(-1)

Out[52]:
  age  job  country
0  30  1.0   France
1  25  0.0    Italy
2  22 -1.0  Germany
3  40  2.0     EEUU
4  34  1.0      NaN
5  50  2.0   France
```

---

**Note**: `clerk` is ordinal ordering before `lawyer`, so its ordinal-encoded value must smaller `lawyer`. So `clerk` is `0` and `lawyer` is `1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution if you want to use None values as the 0th index of the category

**Note: Here I have the same list of category items so I used the same list for each column, you might have different lists**

```
all_categories = data[["columns", "you", "want"]].values.ravel()
all_categories = [i for i in all_categories if pd.notnull(i)]
unique_categories = [None] + list(pd.unique(all_categories))

oe_cat = OrdinalEncoder(handle_unknown='use_encoded_value', unknown_value=-1, categories=[unique_categories for _ in ["columns", "you", "want"]])
oe_cat.fit(merged[["columns", "you", "want"]])
```